# Properties of a function $f=f(x,y)$ with maximum in $(x_{0},y_{0})$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I wanted to ask about the following statement.

Let $f=f(x,y)$, $f$ is maximum at ($x_{0},y_{0}$).

Show that:

1)$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_{0},y_{0})=0$ y $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_{0},y_{0})=0$

2)$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x_{0},y_{0})<0$ y $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x_{0},y_{0})<0$

3)$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x_{0},y_{0})-\frac{\left(\frac{\partial^2 f}{ \partial x\partial y}(x_{0},y_{0})\right)^2}{\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(x_{0},y_{0})}<0$

They let me do this show, but I do not remember how to do it strictly. I wanted to ask if anyone knew a good book or pdf where comes the show, or if someone can develop a sketch show on the page. For any help, thank you very much.

Comment: Does it say "$f$ is maximum" or "$f$ has a local maximum"? If the maximum is on the boundary of the domain, then the derivatives need not be zero.

Comment: Hello, well I want to show the second derivative test for function of two variable

Comment: The formatting seems off in statements (1) and (2). There seems to be a stray letter "y" in each of those statements. (Or is that the Spanish word "y"?)

Comment: The hypothesis should say "local maximum." Statement (1) is not true without the word "local." For example, consider $f(x,y) = -|xy|$. This has a maximum at $(0, 0)$ but the derivatives in statement (1) do not exist at $(0,0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is statement (1) proved in a popular Calculus textbook. See "Theorem 2" here: http://tinyurl.com/m6ywrx4.

The "Fermat's theorem" they refer to is proved here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_theorem_(stationary_points)

Comment: (Per my comment above, note the word "local" in the theorem.)